# Don't show Configurable Product Combination when not in Stock

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, configurable-product, out-of-stock

Is it possible in a configurable Product to hide (or simply not show) certain combinations that are not in stock?

Let's say I have a shirt that has the options color and size.

All shirts are in stock and available except for the shirt that has the color red and the size XL.

When i try to add this combination of the shirt to the cart, the product page reloads and shows the message of the method getSpecifyOptionMessage().

There is no direct hint, that this combination of the product is not available and this could be confusing for the customers, since they will try it again and have no direct information, why they can't add this product to cart.

Is it possible, not to show these options / combinations that are not available? You first select the color and then the not available combinations are not displayed in the drop-down for the size?

Searched a lot for something like this but could not find anything directly related to this situation. Therefore i would be very thankful if somebody could provide any useful information or a solution for this situation.

Comment: Hey HausE we can disable that product which is out of stock so that particular product won't be visible.

Comment: @ShubhamKhandelwal Thank your for this input. That works perfectly. But i have the feeling that our PM is not very happy about this, since he will say, that he cannot check all child products of configurable products and disable all the ones, that are not in stock. So therefore it would be amazing, if this would work the same way, just when a product is not in stock and not disabled. But thank you anyway :) Will check this with the PM.

Comment: we can do it but it and at once it will disable all out of stock product but it will take time .i can share the approach that how we can do it if you want.

Comment: @ShubhamKhandelwal Thank you for the help and your suggestion but this is not necessary. I already made a few scripts/ methods to change products programmatically and also made one for bundle and config children. It's more an administrative Problem now than a technical problem :) But like I said, thank you anyway.

Comment: Yeah Your welcome Brother if you need any help regarding this feel free to ask we can work on it :)